# How to force spark to complete a stage before another stage start?

Tags: apache-spark

Env: Spark 1.2.0 running on yarn-client mode. Problem won't appear in local mode.

Task: use a RDD1 to create a Map, then use this Map on RDD2.map().

Exception: caused on Map says no such keys(which must be there, data is absolutely correct). I assume this is caused by using a Map that is not in its final stage.

failed solution1:

use `val bcMap = RDD2.context.broadcast(Map)` instead. Btw this worked before.

failed solution2:
`val Map = CreateMap(RDD1.collect)` This also worked before.

failed solution3:
combine them both. Worked before

Successful:

do some weird stuff that actually do nothing good but wasting CPU time, like `Map.keys.foreach(println)`

Additional:

The 3 failed solutions are not completely failed, they do work in some stage, but then I wrote some more code between MakingMap() and UseMap() they all began to fail.

I guess this is caused by Spark DAG scheduler which believes that those tasks have nothing related then run them both simultaneously( I'm very surprised that broadcast can't help me this time). I just wonder if there is a way to tell DAG scheduler how to deal with them or just force some work stop lazy?

Comment: Please share some example code that shows the whole data flow in your maps. In particular, we'd like to see `MakingMap`and `UseMap`.

Comment: Stages are scheduled following their dependency graph. The assumption made here does not stand. There's probably another kind of issue. Could you post the code?

Comment: Other exception raises and this one disappeared. weird. I may need more time to dig it out.